# ReentrantReadWriteLock - locking / releasing in if - else block

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a question on ReadwriteLocks good practice.  I've only ever used synchronized blocks before, so please bear with me.

Is the code below a correct way in which to use a ReadWriteLock?  That is,

Obtain the lock in the private method.

If a condition is met, return from the private method having not released the lock.  Release the lock in the public method.

Alternatively:

Obtain the lock in the private method.

If the condition is not met, release the lock immediately in the private method.

Many thanks

```
private List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

private ReadWriteLock listLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock

public int methodA(int y) {
    ...........
    long ago = methodB(y);
    list.remove(y);
    listLock.writeLock().unlock();
}

private long methodB(int x) {
    listLock.writeLock().lock();
    if(list.contains(x) {
        long value = // do calculations on x
        return value;
    }
    else {
        listLock.writeLock().unlock();
        // return something else unconnected with list
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Normally when using locks you would do something similar to this.

```
Lock lock = ...; // Create type of lock
lock.lock();
try {
    // Do synchronized stuff
}
finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

This ensures that the lock is always unlocked at the end of the block. No matter if there is an exception thrown. Since you are using a reentrant lock you can place this in both methods and it will work correctly, not releasing the lock until the last finally block executes.

Edit: Javadocs for the [Lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) interface reinterates what I posted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I guess I wanted to release the lock asap if the condition wasn't met - that's why it's released in the private method in that case.  Is this OK to do so - having code that releases the lock depending on whether some condition is met?

Comment: In this case, when the condition is not met you would just exit the try-finally block and the lock will be unlocked. The idea is not to enclose an entire method inside the try-finally block, only the parts that require locking. It's always best to do locks within a try-finally block to ensure locks are always unlocked.